# On [for="description"]' click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ty52mdjd/)**

I am trying if a label has attribute `for="description"` on click should focus an other element.

I have tried following but its not working. Is this possible to get click event on an attribute. Or what other can be possibilities to achieve this? other than adding a class or id.

```
$('[for="description"]').on('Click', function() {
    console.log('test');
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Why using `for` attribute if you don't want the default behaviour of `for` attribute?

Comment: Oh God, what a silly mistake I made...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in **Click** event keyword. It should lowercase. Look this code:

```
$('[for="description"]').on('click', function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Otherwise, you have not define an element with class name `nicEdit-main`.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/habibillah/7mtaLL35/1/)

Comment: he used "." mean its not tag.. its class.. mind it

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the event name is `click` - note the lowercase `c`. Secondly, `console` is not a property of a jQuery object - it's on the `window` object. Try this:

```
$('[for="description"]').on('click', function () {
    console.log('test');
    alert('test');
});
```

> on click should focus an other element

You get this behaviour for free if you provide an `input`, `textarea` or `select` element with an `id` attribute which matches the `for` in the `label`.

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ty52mdjd/5/)

Comment: `on click should focus an other element` :)

Comment: @A. Wolff this is true for label elements but may (depending on browser) not have the same effect for non label elements.

Comment: @Nico AFAIK, `for` attribute is only valid for `label` element. I'm not sure which kind of other elements are you talking about

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: is `.on("click")` no `.on("Click")`. Also `$('.nicEdit-main').console.log('test');` console is not property of jquery object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent default behaviour of label click with `for` attribute set:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[for="description"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.nicEdit-main').focus();
    });
});
```

But then the question is, why in first place are you setting `for` attribute? Use instead any custom attribute, e.g: `data-for`